# Angular JS number filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had the following expression in Angular:

```
<br/><i>{{getFieldValue(teamMember.reportingData.fields, fieldname, 'meanValue' | number:2)}}</i>
```

where `getFieldValue` is a function on my controller. This was working as expected, and truncating the numeric result to 2 decimal places.

However, sometimes `getFieldValue` returns a string result. When that happens, it is not displayed at all. This is probably because truncating a  string to 2 decimal places does not make sense.

To get round this, I tried to move the filter inside `getFieldValue` and only apply it to numeric results. To do this, I need a way of specifying a filter in Javascript, not as an expression in HTML. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) this is possible, but the explanation is hard to follow.

Here is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<br/><i>{{getFieldValue(teamMember.reportingData.fields, fieldname, 'meanValue')}}</i>
```

part of getFieldValue :

```
if (field.numeric) {
   fieldValue = $filter('number')([], field[aggregate], 2);
 } else {
   fieldValue = field[aggregate];
 }
```

This does not work, I get what seems to be an empty string back. How to I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
 fieldValue = $filter('number')(field[aggregate], 2);
```

See [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) of `number` filter.

Comment: thanks for that. The doc page is much clearer than the filter doc page I had seen. Works now.

Comment: I will when it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   var isnum = angular.isNumber(field[aggregate]);

    if(isnum){   
        fieldValue = $filter('number')(field[aggregate], 2) 
    }else{   
        fieldValue = field[aggregate]; 
     }
```

[number filter in angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)